# Acceder a un textfield desde una clase

Tags: ios, swift

Tengo una clase creada en cocoa para dibujar unas líneas rectas en la pantalla, corro la aplicación y dibuja todo en las coordenadas que le doy. Sin embargo quiero poder asignarle los valores desde un `textfield` que está en el `viewcotroller`, pero me bota error.

Primero en la clase creo el objeto así:

```
 var texto:ViewController?
```

después iniciativo el objeto y cuando quiero leer la propiedad `text` me tira error, así es como lo leo:

```
texto = ViewController()
leeTexto = texto?.valores.text
```

Ahora cuando quiero llamar la función lo hago así:

```
@IBAction func angulo(sender: UIButton) {
    let recta = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 512, height: 512)
    objetoDibujo = DrawExamples()
    objetoDibujo?.drawRect(recta)
}
```

y esta es la estructura de la función:

```
override func drawRect(rect: CGRect) {
}
```

adjunto la imagen del error:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola @joseluis. ¡Bienvenido a [es.so]! Si se está disparando un error, lo mejor sería [edit] la pregunta agregando el texto de ese error.

Answer (score 2):

Si el problema con la expresión `texto?.valores.text` es que encontró `nil`, lo único que puede ser `nil` es `valores`...

Te sugiero que revises la inicialización de la variable `valores` en la clase `ViewController`.

En todo caso, si `valores` puede ser `nil`, deberías escribirlo como:

```
leerText = texto?.valores?.text
```

o de esta forma:

```
if let valores = texto?.valores {
    leerTexto = valores.text
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Al parecer estás inicializando mal el ViewController `texto`. En la captura que subiste se muestra que la variable `valores` tiene in `@IBOutlet`, por lo que está relacionada con un storyboard o un archivo .nib.

Asumiendo que estás usando la configuración por defecto, es decir un `UIStoryboard` llamado Main que dentro tiene un `UIViewController` llamado ViewController, debes usar el siguiente código:

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(named: "Main", bundle: nil)
let texto = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("ViewController") as! ViewController
```

De lo contrario, si el ViewController está dentro de un archivo nib (asumamos que se llama ViewController.xib), debes inicializarlo de la siguiente forma:

```
let texto = NSBundle.mainBundle().loadNibNamed("ViewController", owner: nil, options: nil).first as! ViewController
```

Answer (score 0):

al inicializar la cadena, debes ponerla de la siguiente manera

```
var cadena: String = ""
```

y cuando vas a leer lo que tiene un textfield debes evitar que el valor sea nulo con lo siguiente

```
cadena = textfield.text! // El signo de exclamación forza que sea texto y no nil
```

Espero te ayude, saludos!